# C# Asynchronous Lock class

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm wrote Asynchronous Lock provider for reducing lock that breaks `async` keyword.

All tasks with `async` and `await` keywords are chained by `GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(Callback)` on I know. But some cases are not, for example: `lock` keyword, `EventObject.Wait()`, Mutex like objects... etc.

So, I think that if asynchronous chainable lock is possible, it can improve `async` performance.

```
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronous Lock Provider.
/// </summary>
public class AsyncLock
{
    private Task m_Current = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Wait the lock asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IDisposable> WaitAsync()
    {
        var Current = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        while (true)
        {
            Task Latest = null;

            lock (this)
            {
                if (m_Current is null || m_Current.IsCompleted)
                {
                    m_Current = Current.Task;
                    break;
                }

                Latest = m_Current;
            }

            await Latest;
        }

        return new ReleaseOnDispose(() => Current.TrySetResult(true));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release on Dispose.
    /// </summary>
    private struct ReleaseOnDispose : IDisposable
    {
        private Action m_Release;

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct a new ReleaseAsync structure using Release functor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Release"></param>
        public ReleaseOnDispose(Action Release)
            => m_Release = Release;

        /// <summary>
        /// Release the Lock on dispose.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose() => m_Release?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read bytes with buffered.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Length"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(int Length)
{
    using (await m_ReadLock.WaitAsync())
    {
        byte[] Output = m_Buffer.Take(Length);

        if (Output.Length <= 0)
        {
            int Read = await m_Link.ReadAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(m_ByteBuffer));
            if (Read <= 0)
            {
                await m_Link.CloseAsync();
                return null;
            }

            if (Read > Length)
            {
                m_Buffer.Append(m_ByteBuffer, Length, Read - Length);
                Read = Length;
            }

            Array.Resize(ref Output, Read);
            Array.Copy(m_ByteBuffer, 0, Output, 0, Read);
        }

        return Output;
    }
}
```

1. Is this really better than traditionally used locks?
2. Can my code be accepted on commercial development?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SemaphoreSlim` provides async locking out-of-the-box.

```
using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

// ...

await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    // critical section code
}
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

> Is this really better than traditionally used locks?

Nope. Because you're just wrapping monitors with new `Task` instance spawn. It could be inefficient in performance.

> Can my code be accepted on commercial development?

There's no sense in general to use the provided solution as .NET provides already existent and well-implemented one.